# How to add data to a relationship with multiple foreign keys in Django?

Tags: python, database, django

How to add data to a relationship with multiple foreign keys in Django?

I'm building a simulation written in python and would like to use django's orm to store (intermediate and final) results in a database. Therefore I am not concerned with urls and views.

The problem I am having is the instantiation of an object with multiple ForeinKeys. This object is supposed to represent the relationship between an agent and a time step.

Here is the code:

I'm using the following models

```
from django.db import models
import random
from django.contrib.admin.util import related_name

# Create your models here.
class Agent(models.Model):

    agent = int
    def __init__(self, agent, *args, **kwargs):
        models.Model.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.agent = agent

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.agent)

class Step(models.Model):

    step = int

    def __init__(self, step, *args, **kwargs):
        models.Model.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.step = step

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.step)


class StepAgentData(models.Model):

    def __init__(self, step, agent, *args, **kwargs):
        models.Model.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.step = step  #This does not work
        self.agent = agent

    step = models.ForeignKey(Step, related_name='time_step')
    agent = models.ForeignKey(Agent, related_name='associated_agent')
    data = float    

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str("Step %s \t Agent %s ", (self.step,self.agent))
```

Running the following script

```
from DBStructureTest.App.models import Step, Agent, StepAgentData

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = Step(1)
    s.save()
    a = Agent(2)
    a.save()
    sad = StepAgentData(s,a)
    sad.save()

    print "finished"
```

results in the following error message when self.step = step is executed in the constructor of the StepAgentData (see comment in the code of the StepAgentData model)

```
>  File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py",
> line 367, in __set__
>     val = getattr(value, self.field.rel.get_related_field().attname)  
> File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py",
> line 773, in get_related_field
>     data = self.to._meta.get_field_by_name(self.field_name)   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/options.py",
> line 307, in get_field_by_name
>     cache = self.init_name_map()   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/options.py",
> line 337, in init_name_map
>     for f, model in self.get_all_related_m2m_objects_with_model():  
> File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/options.py",
> line 414, in get_all_related_m2m_objects_with_model
>     cache = self._fill_related_many_to_many_cache()   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/options.py",
> line 428, in _fill_related_many_to_many_cache
>     for klass in get_models():   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py",
> line 167, in get_models
>     self._populate()   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py",
> line 61, in _populate
>     self.load_app(app_name, True)   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py",
> line 76, in load_app
>     app_module = import_module(app_name)   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py",
> line 35, in import_module
>     __import__(name) ImportError: No module named App
```

The folder structure is the following:

```
|-DBStructureTest
    |-App
        |-__init__.py       
        |-Main.py
        |-models.py
        |-test.py
        |-views.py
    |-__init__.py
    |-manage.py
    |-settings.py
    |-urls.py
```

What am I doing wrong? Help is very much appreciated.

EDIT:
In the /App directory I get the following after doing 'import models'
`

> > > import models
> > >           Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >             File "", line 1, in 
> > >             File "models.py", line 1, in 
> > >               from django.db import models
> > >             File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/**init**.py", line 14, in 
> > >               if not settings.DATABASES:
> > >             File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 276, in **getattr**
> > >               self._setup()
> > >             File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line 40, in _setup
> > >               raise ImportError("Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable %s is undefined." % ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
> > >           ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
> > >       '

Comment: my guess is that DBStructureTest also has to have \_\_init\_\_.py in it.

Comment: Thanks akonsu, but there is already a __init__.py in the DBStructureTest. Further ideas?

Comment: can you load the module from a python prompt? given that it is in your PYTHONPATH.

Comment: thanks akonsu, I edited my question to reflect your comment. Help is still appreciated!

Comment: these are two different problems. the original one is because it seems that you are running your script from DBStructureTest directory, so it is trying to find DBStructureTest subdirectory under it. the second one is self-explanatory, you need to set the env var or run "manage.py shell"

Comment: akonsu, Thank You! Moving the Main.py (my script) from the /App directory to the DBStructureTest Package (parent directory of /App) saved the situation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

these are two different problems. the original one is because it seems that you are running your script from DBStructureTest directory, so it is trying to find DBStructureTest subdirectory under it. the second one is self-explanatory, you need to set the env var or run "manage.py shell"

BTW, I do not see any database fields in your models. Do the corresponding SQL tables contain anything?

Comment: Good hint with the missing fields! Adding models.IntegerField() to the Agent and Step classes got me rid of a IntegrityError.

Answer (score 0):

First, you might want to use a ManyToMany-relationship for the the StepAgent-Class. You can also have [extra fields on many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) and it will be better design.

For your error you have to `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings` or however the settingsmodule can be reached from the current `PYTHONPATH`, otherwise django does not know where to find and how to set up your settings.